# By mistake change sudoers owner

Tags: permissions, sudo

So, i by mistake change ownership for a lot of files. I asked my provider to reinstall OS but their answer was that i will have to pay 50 EUR an hour for technician.

i need to get back sudo premisions.

sudo gives me error:

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers.d is owned by uid 1000, should be 0
```

WinSCP shows

[image]

I tried a lot of things, was going thru web for like 3 hours and still no changes.
I can boot into recovery mode, tried thru there but still nothing.

Comment: In recovery mode you should at least be able to `chown root:root /etc/sudoers.d` and solve the above error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in recovery mode, you will see # there. It means you already have access.
change permission of the files you want to by using chmod command :

```
chmod 774 /etc/sudoers.d
```

If all fails, why not just create a new user. And if you find this too tedious, you can run a live usb, chroot into the environment, take a backup and re-install the OS. 
This is a template for chroot, don't use it directly, change the values to suit your directory structure. If this seems too advanced, post output of command 'mount' in recovery mode.

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt/ /dev/sda
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
sudo chroot /mnt update-grub
sudo umount /mnt/sys
sudo umount /mnt/dev
sudo umount /mnt/proc
```

Comment: Oh, my mistake was that i was trying to fix /etc/sudoers from all the tutorials in the internet, but didn`t realize that my error was /etc/sudoers.d

Comment: @user3241944 : Ya, okay...did you try the command, first one I mean.

Comment: yeah, and chown to sudoers.d too.

Comment: Good, please upvote the answer as well if it worked. Thanks.

Comment: @WeareBorg Don't be so reputation-greedy! ;-D Besides, a 3-points user can't upvote yet...

Comment: @ByteCommander : Doch!!! Building my profile mann.. ;-) ..